# quantification z stack image j

Tags: image, imagej

For the quantification of MAS protein in z stack images, I start by doing a MaxIntensity Z projection, then I reduce background with Background Substruction tool.

At this point I can easily make a macro to process multiple images.

My problem is that I dont know how to include the thresholding part in my macro. I do the thresholding manually by overlaying the thresholding red with the colored signal I am interested in.
After that i just measure the %area.

My measurements are presented as " stained area/total area "

I would like to find a way to define automatically the Max and Min threshold values, that perfectly align the threshold with the signal and measure that area.

Comment: As you may have realized, it is not a good idea to set thresholds, neither manually nor by a macro. To generalize thresholds, i.e. that they work with various images of the same kind, you need to use one of the provided threshold-schemes that determine thresholds automatically. If none of the schemes work for you, you either need to code one that fits your needs (not trivial), or you need to take greater care with your sample preparations. Fiji comes with "Auto Local Threshold" that you may try as well.